# How do I use aysnc/await in this superagent call?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, mobx, superagent

This is a superagent call, I have imported request(i.e is exported from my superagent component class)
How do I use async/await in this for "res.resImpVariable".

```
request
  .post(my api call)
  .send(params) // an object of parameters that is to be sent to api 
  .end((err, res) => {
  if(!err) {
     let impVariable = res.resImpVariable;
  } else {
    console.log('error present');
   }
  });
```

Comment: This works on callback pattern and hence to move it into async-await will need you to convert the change to return promise

Comment: sure, how do I add it in the code?

Comment: https://visionmedia.github.io/superagent/#promise-and-generator-support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reformulated my answer. I think I was misinterpreting before. You could wrap the entire sequence into a Promise-returning function that resolves after the response callback:

```
    function callSuperagent() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            return request
                .post(my api call)
                .send(params) // an object of parameters that is to be sent to api
                .end((err, res) => {
                    if(!err) {
                        console.log('get response', res);
                        // uncomment this to see the catch block work
                        // reject('Bonus error.');
                        resolve(res);
                    } else {
                        console.log('error present', err);
                        reject(err);
                    }
                });
        });
    }
```

Then, you can create an async function and await that:

```
    async function doSomething() {
        try {
            const res = await callSuperagent();

            // uncomment this to see the catch block work
            // throw 'Artificial error.';

            console.log('res', res);

            console.log('and our friend:', res.resImpVariable);
        } catch (error) {
            throw new Error(`Problem doing something: ${error}.`);
        }
    }

    doSomething();
```

Or if you don't make `doSomething`, it would be like this:

```
callSuperagent()
    .then((res) => {
        console.log('res', res);
        console.log('and our friend:', res.resImpVariable);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log('err', err);
    })
```

Comment: thankyou, where do I add the doSomething method? immediately after resolve?

Comment: Everything is included inside there. You would replace everything you have now with two function definitions (which could be anywhere in that file) and just the one call to `doSomething()`. It's very hard for me to improve what I'm saying because I can't see what comes before and after `request.post().send().end()`